# Acts_as_Version is there a way to skip a versioning from occurring on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-versioned

Using rails acts_as_versioned, is there a way to skip a versioning event from happening, and just allowing a regular save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could do either of these:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
# assign some stuff to your post
@post.save_without_revision
```

or

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@post.without_revision do
  @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
end
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work. I think it might be because I'm using paperclip for image attachments. And paperclip is doing it's own saving method that isn't even looking at something like "acts_as_versioned :if => Proc.new { |attachment| ....

Answer (score 1):

if i remember correcly

```
record.save_without_revision
```

should do the trick